# string comparison not recognizing match

Tags: python, string, comparison

I have a list of urls in 'origFile' that will be augmented and written into 'readyFile'. I want to add urls to 'readyFile' only if they are not already in the 'readyFile'.

```
with open('bpBlacklist.txt', 'r') as origFile, open('bpBlacklistReady','r+') as readyFile :
    for line in origFile:       
        orig_string = line.strip()
        if orig_string in readyFile.read():
            None
        else: 
            readyFile.write( "'" + orig_string + "'," + '\n' )

    origFile.close()    
    readyFile.close()
```

Right now, it just rewrites the whole list into 'readyFile' every time I run it. I tried moving the "'+ str + '" augmentation outside the if statement but the problem persisted.

Comment: You don't need the `file.close()` lines, as you opened the files in a `with` block. They will close when you exit the block.

Comment: That `None` should be replaced with `continue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `readyFile.write(...)` your next `readyFile.read()` call will be overwritten. You should save your readyFile content into a variable right after the `with` statement:

```
with open('bpBlacklist.txt', 'r') as origFile, open('bpBlacklistReady','r+') as readyFile :
     readyFileContent = readyFile.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition doesn't work as you expect because the `read()` method will return the whole file as a string. You need to check the membership between an iterable of urls.

And instead of looping over the file and check the membership for all the urls you can find the difference using `set.difference()` function then write the extra urls:

```
with open('bpBlacklist.txt', 'r') as origFile, open('bpBlacklistReady','r+') as readyFile :
    current = set(origFile)
    diffs = current.difference(readyFile.readlines())
    for url in diffs:
        readyFile.write(url + '\n')
```

Comment: its still rewriting the whole list into the readyFile with your changes

Comment: @pproctor Are you sure? maybe they all are different!

Comment: well all the urls in origFile are different but they don't change unless I add another manually. I'm a bit confused what you mean